# SAS Merge : merge and also prevent values to be replaced with missing

Tags: sas

Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER it is not about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform. If the latter, you could try the support links we maintain.

Closed 2 mins ago.

(Private feedback for you)

Edit question
Delete question
I wan to result has four records: 1 11; 2 22; 3 33; 6 66

And I do not want the 22 for the 2nd obs be replaces with a missing.

```
data e1;
input id1 v1 ;
datalines;
1 . 2 22 3 . ; run;

data e2;
input id1 v1;
datalines; 1 11 2 . 3 33 6 66 ; run;

data e3; merge e1(in=ine1) e2(in=ine2); by id1; run;

proc print ; run;
```

Comment: You may want to edit this question to make it more clear. I don't think your data statements will work either, so please verify the code shown at least creates the data you have correctly.

Comment: Looks like you want to use UPDATE and not MERGE.